# How to compare a string in batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I am writing a batch script as follows:

```
 @echo off
 setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
 set Current_Node="Node1"
 if "%Current_Node%" == "Node1" (
 echo "ITS INSIDE IF LOOP"
 ) else (
echo "ITS NOT INSIDE IF LOOP"
)
```

Now,according to above code it should not go to the else part but in actual it is always entering to the else part.
I am not getting whether the problem is in syntax or the way i am comparing the strings.
So, please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You have too many quotes. Don't use quotes when setting the value or do not use quotes on `"%Current_Node%"`. 
When you use `Current_Node="Node1"`, %Current_Node%  will be equal to "Node1", but "%Current_Node%" will be equal to ""Node1"".

```
@echo off
 setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
 set Current_Node=Node1
echo %Current_Node%
 if "%Current_Node%" == "Node1" (
 echo ITS INSIDE IF LOOP
 ) else (
echo ITS NOT INSIDE IF LOOP
)
```

Comment: thank you so much it was of great help, i was so confused with this .

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, there are quotes used where not necessary. I believe you need to use EQU instead of == etc. Try below if still having trouble.

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set Current_Node=Node1

if %Current_Node% EQU Node1 (
    echo ITS INSIDE IF LOOP
) else (
    echo ITS NOT INSIDE IF LOOP
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Double quotes are sometimes needed when setting a variable, so the solution can be simply to wrap the term in double quotes as seen in line two below.  They do not become part of the variable.

```
@echo off
set "Current_Node=Node1"
if "%Current_Node%" == "Node1" (
   echo "ITS INSIDE IF LOOP"
) else (
   echo "ITS NOT INSIDE IF LOOP"
)
```